# Accessing ARGV in a compiled ruby script

Tags: java, jruby

If we try to pass arguments via command line to a ruby script, we can access those arguments via ARGV variable. Considering the following file "script.rb":

```
  puts ARGV
```

If we call this script using the command line: *jruby script.rb Arg1 Arg2*, then we get the expected output:

```
  Arg1
  Arg2
```

as expected. However, if we compile the script and then call the script using *java*, there's no output.

```
  jrubyc script.rb
  java script Arg1 Arg2
  <Expected to see Arg1 Arg2, but nothing is printed>
```

Is there a specific way to pass arguments? What am I missing?